# Local video on iPhone (m4v format) - Play video at a specific time-index

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a PhoneGap application, in which I'm linking directly to video files, which in turn opens up the internal player and starts playback...

```
<a href="video.m4v">Play Video</a>
```

Is it possible to start linked-to videos at a specific time-index, somehow, like you would do on YouTube...?

`youtube.com/watch?v=666w#t=06m12s` (six minutes and twelve seconds in)

... Furthermore; is it possible to specify an end-point?

I am trying to avoid splitting up my video file to save a few megabytes. I want users to be able to download the application anywhere, so I need to limit the size to 20 megabytes or less.